# Extending a Custom Membership Provider

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have made a Custom Membership Provider and implemented what methods i need. I now need to add a custom method of my own which deals with the password.

I have added a new method but i am unable to use it anywhere in code. Is it possible to add methods to my custom membership provider or is this done elsewhere?

Comment: An example of the answer:
((CustomMembershipProvider) Membership.Provider).TestMethod(password);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
((YourProviderType)Membership.Provider).YourMethod();
```